# interpolación en visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

Tengo este código de Visual Studio 2017:

```
public class InvalidObjectPrefixException : MinioException
{
    private readonly string objectPrefix;

    public InvalidObjectPrefixException(string objectPrefix, string message) : base(message)
    {
        this.objectPrefix = objectPrefix;
    }

    public override string ToString() => $"{this.objectPrefix}: {base.ToString()}";

    
}
```

Debo implementarlo en Visual Studio 2013 pero en esta versión no existe la interpolacion, alguien podria darme una idea de como convertir esta linea: `public override string ToString() => $"{this.objectPrefix}: {base.ToString()}";`

Comment: Proba 'string.Concat("{", this.objectPrefix, ":", base.ToString(), "}")'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siempre puedes utilizar [`string.Format()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.0) de la siguiente manera:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0}: {1}", this.objectPrefix, base.ToString());
}
```

Comment: gracias... me fue muy util